# After returning from function when I printed modified string, It shows me the garbage value

Tags: c, string, garbage

```
int main()
{

    //CODE
    printf("Enter the destination string : ");

    char *dest_string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    int le = 0;

    while(dest_string[le - 1] != '\n')
    {
        dest_string = (char *)realloc(dest_string,sizeof(char) * (le + 1) );
        dest_string[le] = getchar();
        le++;
    }

    *(dest_string + le - 1) = '\0';
    le = 0;


    printf("Enter the source string : ");
    char *source_string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    le = 0;

    while(source_string[le - 1] != '\n')
    {
        source_string = (char *)realloc(source_string,sizeof(char) *  ( le + 1 ) );

        source_string[le] = getchar();

        le++;
    }

    *(source_string + le - 1) = '\0';

    _concatenate(dest_string, source_string);

    puts(dest_string);

    free(dest_string);
    free(source_string);

    exit(0);
}

/* following function takes two parameter, first parameter is
   destination string and second parameter is source string
   This function makes changes to destination string by 
   appending the source string to it */
void _concatenate(char *dest_string, char *source_string){


    int le = 0; // loop enumerator
    int dest_string_len = strlen(dest_string);

    while(source_string[le] != '\0')
    {

        dest_string = (char *)realloc(dest_string,sizeof(char) * (dest_string_len + le + 1) );

        *(dest_string + dest_string_len + le) = *(source_string + le);
        le++;
    }

    dest_string = (char *)realloc(dest_string,sizeof(char) * (dest_string_len + le) );
    *(dest_string + dest_string_len + le  ) = '\0';

    puts(dest_string);

    return ;
}
```

Comment: `while(dest_string[le - 1] != '\n')` and `while(source_string[le - 1] != '\n')` access memory out of bounds on the first iteration. `realloc` in the function won't work as you'd hope because the function is passed a copy of the pointer arguments. You can change them in the function but that change will be lost when the function returns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838038/c-programming-malloc-inside-another-function

Comment: Thanks, I defined function as char* _concatenate( char *, char *), my problem got resolved but still have a little doubt , I passed address to function local pointers so it should be make changes at that address then why it is not visible even if local pointer doesn't exist after returning

Comment: This is a rather low effort question (your comment shows more effort into explaining & trying to understand your own problem), but I bit anyway, mostly because it is interesting how much can go wrong in such a short program. Please take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the reception you'll receive in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Many issues to note here, both major and minor, in no particular order:

1. The two standard signatures for [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) are: `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and `int main(void)`.
2. Identifiers that start with an `_` should be avoided as they are, with very few exceptions, [reserved for the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301/2505965).
3. [`exit(0)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program) at the end of `main` is largely unnecessary, as `main` will implicitly `return 0;` if it reaches its terminating `}` (since C99).
4. `sizeof (char)` is [guaranteed to be `1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).
5. You do not need to cast the return of `malloc`, as a `void *` can be safely and implicitly converted to any other pointer type. Casting the return is [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965).
6. As pointed out in the comments `if (dest_string[le - 1] != '\n')` will access `dest_string[-1]` on the first iteration, which is out of bounds. This is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). Of course this holds true for the loop involving `source_string` as well.
7. You need to check if [`*alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) functions fail, by testing their return value is not `NULL`. You cannot blindly reassign the return of `realloc`, because in the case where it fails, the original pointer will still be valid, and will you need to `free` the original pointer sooner or later.
8. On the other hand, if `realloc` succeeds, the previous pointer value should be considered invalid. While it's true that the base address of the memory block *may not* have changed, you cannot know this without checking first, and it is rather pointless to test if they are the same. If the return is not `NULL`, simply use that pointer.
9. You need to test if [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns the end-of-file marker (`EOF`), otherwise, if it ever occurs, you're going to loop until you run out of memory.

You haven't shown us any [headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header), so I have to assume you didn't include them. You'll need

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Whenever you repeat yourself, it's almost always a sign that you should recompose those sections into some form of abstraction. In this example, the identical sections of code you've written to build strings from [`stdin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams) should be reduced into a function.

Since you do not error check [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), we have to assume it always succeeds. As such, #8 on our list shows us that `dest_string` in `main` cannot reliably be assumed to point to valid memory after the call to `_concatenate`, which *may have* moved the data located at that pointer, and freed the old data

> If there is not enough room to enlarge the memory allocation pointed to by ptr, realloc() creates a new allocation, copies as much of the old data pointed to by ptr as will fit to the new allocation, frees the old allocation, and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.

and so `puts(dest_string)` might access invalid or uninitialized memory, and `free(dest_string)` might cause a [double free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057393/what-does-double-free-mean).

You use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to get the length of your destination string, but then you manually count and copy the source string. Using other standard library functions makes this much cleaner:

```
char *concat(char *dest, char *src) {
    size_t dest_len = strlen(dest),
           src_len = strlen(src);

    char *p = realloc(dest, dest_len + src_len + 1);

    return p ? strcat(p, src) : NULL;
}
```

As you can see, managing the memory and doing the actual string operation should really be separate concerns; [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) doesn't care if the destination buffer is dynamically allocated or not, as long as the caller makes sure there's enough space for the result.

Reallocating for every byte is not a great strategy, but it is simple, and does work.

---

Here's a complete example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *concat(char *, char *);
char *input(const char *);

int main(void) {
    char *dest = input("Enter the destination string : "),
         *source = input("Enter the source string : "),
         *result;

    if (!dest || !source || !(result = concat(dest, source))) {
        free(dest);
        free(source);

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts(result);

    free(result);
    free(source);
}

char *concat(char *dest, char *src) {
    size_t dest_len = strlen(dest),
           src_len = strlen(src);

    char *p = realloc(dest, dest_len + src_len + 1);

    return p ? strcat(p, src) : NULL;
}

char *input(const char *msg) {
    int ch;
    size_t length = 0;
    char *buf = malloc(1),
         *rebuf;

    if (!buf) return NULL;
    if (msg) printf("%s", msg);

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if (!(rebuf = realloc(buf, length + 1))) {
            free(buf);
            return NULL;
        }

        (buf = rebuf)[length++] = ch;
    }

    buf[length] = '\0';

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your explanation, I can clearly see where I was went wrong

Comment: @leo_7348 Please do consider [accepting the answer if it best solves your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)